# Custom function to convert a decimal integer to binary (upto 20 digits) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, binary, decimal

I need to write a user-defined MATLAB function that converts integers written in binary form to decimal form. Name the function d = binaTOint(b), where the input argument b is a vector with 1s and 0s that represents the binary number to be converted and the output argument d is a number in decimal form. The largest number that could be converted with the function should be a binary number with 20 1s. If a larger number is entered for b, the function should display an error message.

Comment: just when I thought this is not a homework.............

Comment: @ha9u63ar why are you answering then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
function result = binaToInt(number)

% Assuming that the system is a little endian i.e.
% LSB is on the right

if ~(all(number>=0) && all(number<=1))
    error('Only 0s and 1s are allowed');
elseif length(number) > 20
    error('Maximum 20 digits allowed');
end

number = int32(number); % Convert the types appropriately
result = 0; % Pre allocate 0 (that's the minimum anyway)

% Loop through numbers;
n = length(number);
for i = 1:n
    result = result + (number(i)*(2^(n-i)));
end
```

Tets

```
[0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0] gives out 10
[1 1] gives out 3
[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1] gives out 7
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1] gives out 1048575
[0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1] gives out error because only 20 digits are allowed.
```

***Remember that using 2s complement arithmetic is quite useful in this kind of situations.*** If you actually want to use 2s completement, the modifications required will be:

> ```
> Force users to enter 20 digits where the MSB 1 means negative, 0 means positive
> and you need to do the maths accordingly (i.e. subtract/add the MSB with the rest of the digits when accumulating the sum.
> ```